# Headphones don't work with RealTek drivers and Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Ever since upgrading to Windows 10 my headphones no longer work.

The headphones work in other devices.
They work while in Linux, so the port is fine.

I have an Asus UX32VD, and Asus has stopped releasing driver updates.

I have a Realtek sound card.

Driver is 6.0.1.7541, x64 R2.79 downloaded from here:

http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false

Updating the driver through Device Manager DOES update the driver, but the updated driver has the same issue.

Here is a screenshot of all my settings:

http://paragon.media.storage.s3.amazonaws.com/misc/AudioSettings.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like RealTek JUST released a new driver as of this writing - 10/12/2015.

6.0.1.7628

Installed it and now my headphones work.

Forum discussion for reference:

http://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/5993-latest-realtek-hd-audio-driver-version-33.html

Download:

ftp://ftp3.realtek.com.tw/Realtek/GeneralRelease/7628_PG435_Win10_Win8.1_Win8_Win7_WHQL.zip

username : spcust

password : hwwk758z

Answer (score 1):

I searched online for some more recent drivers and found these:

Realtek HD Audio Driver 6.0.1.7624 WHQL

ftp://spcust:hwwk758z@ftp3.realtek.c..._Win7_WHQL.zip

Win 7,8,8.1,10 x32/64
PackageVersion = PG435
DriverVer= 09/25/2015, 6.0.1.7624

Try to install these and look if it may help your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately this version still doesn't work for me.